# Refresh page in Angular 5

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I have in my angular 5 + MVC application this structure `https://localhost:8080/#Home` and in `_Layout.cshtml` a `<base href=“/“>` but when I refresh the page the application go to the login page.
How is the best way to refresh page and stay on the same page?

There is no Auth Guard implemented yet.

Thanks

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: If you want help debugging a problem we need to at least see your code

Answer (score 0):

Kram_ If you are making a login page I assume you always want the user to be sent back to the login page if they aren't logged in correct? I suggest that you put in an Authguard. This will check to see if your user is logged in and then will direct them to the appropriate page.

This [page](https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards) should help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

**Put code when you what to reload page:**

```
    window.location.reload(true);
```